# Rendering in blender wont use GPU

Tags: gpu, blender

Hi Im useing a 1050ti and did all the advised steps to turn on GPU rendering but blender wont use my GPU
the integrated GPU is around 5-8% use
The 1050ti is around 3-5% use , there is usually an initial spike of use around 10-15% but only for a moment
The CPU is a i7-8750H and is usually between 40-100% use during render

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the Preferences - System and than change the Cycles Rendering Devices to CUDA. CUDA uses the graphics card of the system (if they support it, but most NVidia cards can do that). If you render your image make sure to select Cycles as render engine under the render tab.