# blender 3.3 is not using gpu in my computer

Tags: gpu, rendering, blender

I am using nvidia 1060 and intel 7700k. I used blender 3.2 for rendering. it is ok and fast using gpu. But when i updated to blender 3.3 and had done all rendering setting, it uses cpu and cost a lot time.

https://youtu.be/PcpyDHZiTuQ blender 3.2 rendering ok
https://youtu.be/UIGFANNUhc4 blender 3.3 reanding using cpu

This happened before when using 3.2, but after updating nvidia drivers gpu started to work. This time it not works for 3.3.

I have seen other posts:

[Why my GPU load is low when is rendering a scene with Blender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730917/why-my-gpu-load-is-low-when-is-rendering-a-scene-with-blender)

[Rendering in blender wont use GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824845/rendering-in-blender-wont-use-gpu)

They dont work for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in the 2nd video you switched it to None before closing the **Preferences**.

[image: render properties affected with preferences]

In the **Preferences > System** switch it to **Cuda** before closing **Preferences** and then try setting the **Render Properties**.

Comment: Thanks! it works. I thought it was like a tab and need to config each option by choosing the right device.  You helped a lot!

Comment: Mention not mate :)